# Debian: PHP7 not working

Tags: php, linux, repository, debian, apt

I installed PHP7 on Debian but the PHP command is still not found.

I also cannot install it from the repositories as it will simply tell me that **`"php7.0 is not found"`** nor any other component like CLI.

If I use

> **sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php**

It still tells me that it can't find **php7.0** through regex.

Please Guide me.

Comment: The package should be named `php7` not `php7.0`

Comment: E: Unable to locate package php7

Comment: Which Debian version are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add dotdeb repository to install php7.

First add these lines to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/packages.dotdeb.org/ jessie all
deb-src http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/packages.dotdeb.org/ jessie all
```

If you prefer more local mirrors then use one from this page: https://www.dotdeb.org/mirrors/

Then download public pgp key of dotdeb

```
wget https://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg && apt-key add dotdeb.gpg && apt-get update
```

After that install php 7 via

```
apt-get install php
```

Comment: I was trying to compile custom extensions in a `php:7-fpm` Docker container when it couldn't find `php7.0-dev`. This solution worked for me except I had to replace `stable all` with `jessie all` to install it.